# extension function on google earth plugin

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

We are developing this web app: http://projects.igre.emich.edu/iccarsp/
Now we are trying to do the following:

1. upload an image on the viewer
2. adjust the image (*move, rotate etc*) to its accurate location
3. measure the area of the image area (*or maybe digitizing it to measure the frame of the image*)
4. output the result (*the background and the uploaded image*) as KML

I did research it seems that we can do all of this in Google Earth desktop version, so we are trying to do the same thing on web plugin, but Google did not publish the code for these functions(*correct?*)

So I am wondering if there is any other way to do the functions on the web in Google Earth Plugin. Any advice will help thanks!

Comment: Could you please improve the question? It's too hard to read and understand.

Comment: which part?i dont know how to be more clear thx

Answer (score 0):

About area calculation, you can still have a look into  GEarthExtensions:
http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/

The area of a geo.Path Object is accessible via geo.Path.signedArea_
You just need to define a geo.Path around your Image
But there are some limitations:
"The method is inaccurate for large regions because the Earth's curvature is not accounted for." ( from extensions-0.2.1.js)

Hope this can start to help :-)